# Analyse grammaticale d'une phrase dans « Via Mala » , de John Knittel (Albin Michel, p. 303)

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
>
> Enfin, elle reçut une lettre de cette écriture dont elle avait presque abandonné l'espoir de la revoir jamais.

L'antécédent de « dont » est « cette écriture » ; le remplacement du pronom « la » ne peut être à mon avis que « cette écriture ». La subordonnée relative se remplace donc par le texte suivant.

- dont elle avait presque abandonné l'espoir de jamais  revoir cette écriture

La conséquence de ce remplacement est  une proposition dans laquelle « dont » n'a aucune fonction ([dont](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=fonction+de+dont+dans+une+relative)). Le verbe « abandonner » n'a pas de complément introduit par « de » dans ce contexte. Selon ce point de vue la phrase est mal construite, et elle aurait dû être écrite comme suit, à peu de chose près.

- Enfin, elle reçut une lettre de cette écriture qu'elle n'avait presque plus l'espoir de jamais revoir.

Le pronom relatif objet « que » a pour antécédent « cette écriture », et il est le cod de « revoir ».

Est-ce qu'il est possible de confirmer que cette analyse est correcte ou de l'améliorer si elle ne convient pas tout à fait ?  Sinon, si c'est la phrase dans le texte du roman qui est correcte, quelle est l'analyse qui y correspond ?

Comment: Le *dont* est correct pour exprimer la remarque venue du personnage et non pas une conséquence d'un acte passé. Il y a quelque part dans ce lien https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dont une solution à cette question.

Comment: @Personne Il y a une réponse dans le TLFi à l'entrée « dont », mais vous ne savez pas où dans le texte ; c'est ça ?

Comment: En tenant compte de mon précédent commentaire, il y en a plusieurs qui conviennent… à vous voir, la grammaire, c'est votre problème.

Comment: @Personne La grammaire selon moi n'est pas conforme ; j'explique pourquoi (considérations que je juge élémentaires) et je serais surpris de me tromper (elle avait presque abandonné l'espoir de jamais revoir cette écriture [de cette écriture] (dont)) ; cependant, pour l'instant j'ai une confirmation que je ne me trompe pas (réponse acceptée, difficile de demander des références, bien qu'il soit souhaitable d'en avoir)), , et qui reconnait une erreur dans mon raisonnement se doit de me la montrer (ou bien il n'a vraiment rien trouvé).

Comment: Restez dans vos certitudes et continuez à mélanger les différences d'emploi du *dont* et du *que*… le français se parle et s'écoute pour extraire la polysémie des mots.

Comment: @Personne Je mélangerais les différences d'emploi de « dont  » et de « que » ou bien est-ce ce qu'il *faudrait* que je fasse ? Je n'ai pas du tout l'intention de les mélanger : l'utilité de ces différence est trop grande à mes yeux ; de plus je ne crois pas les mélanger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Même si la phrase originale "sonne" bien, sa syntaxe est effectivement incorrecte comme montré par votre analyse.

Par contre, la reformulation "Enfin, elle reçut une lettre de cette écriture qu'elle n'avait presque plus l'espoir de jamais revoir" présente un problème dans la mesure où le complément d'objet direct de "avait" est l'espoir et non l'écriture. A mon sens, le pronom "que" ne peut pas s'appliquer au deuxième verbe ("revoir").

Au vu des exemples indiqués par @LPH dans son commentaire, cette affirmation ("que" ne s'applique pas au deuxième verbe) n'est pas vraiment justifiée, l'éloignement entre le "que" et "revoir" (présence des mots "ne, "presque plus", "jamais") donnant l'impression d'une faute.

Comment: J'ai moi même hésité un moment sur cette question de complément d'objet, pour finalement me croire convaincu que c'était bien le cod de « revoir », ou plus exactement du syntagme verbal « avoir l'espoir de revoir », mais on peut encore en discuter. La phrase suivante, par exemple, où on simplifie (plus de forme négative et d'adverbe), tend à montrer cela : « J'avais retrouvé le titre de ce film que j'avais l'espoir de revoir. ».  Dire, comme vous le faite, que « écriture »  s'impose en tant que patient de « avoir », selon le parallèle, impose que « film » s'applique à « avoir » ; (1/2)

Comment: donc vous contestez la validité de la phrase test ; cependant ne semble-t-elle pas correcte ? Bien sûr, il existe d'autres constructions qui exprime ce qu'on cherche à dire, mais est-ce que celle-ci ne serait pas familière ? (autre ex. : Il y a une question que je cherchais à élucider. ). Je ne pense pas que le « l' »  soit pour grand chose dans cette construction, mais si cela est discutable, il existe quand même de nombreux cas où votre hypothèse n'est pas valide ([« que nous avons espoir de »]( https://www.google.com/search?q=%22que%20nous%20avons%20espoir%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr). (2/2)

Comment: Voilà 3 exemples avec « l' » : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22que%20nous%20avons%20l%27espoir%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr — 
(1846) Le degré d'avancement des travaux que nous avons l'espoir d'ouvrir —
(1965) tout ce que nous avons construit , tout ce que nous avons l'espoir de construire — 
(1967) Il est sans doute vrai que l'Europe que nous essayons de construire , et que nous avons l'espoir de réaliser dans les années qui viennent

Comment: @LPH : Bonne remarque : au vu des exemples fournis, j'ai modifié ma réponse dans ce sens.

Comment: Je peux maintenant accepter votre réponse ; si une autre réponse satisfaisante venait à la contredire, je n'aurai qu'à  faire passer l'acceptation sur cette nouvelle réponse.

Comment: @LPH "Enfin, elle reçut une lettre de cette écriture dont elle avait presque abandonné l'espoir de la revoir jamais." me semble bien sonner. Ou bien: "Enfin, elle reçut une lettre de cette écriture dont elle avait presque abandonné l'espoir de *ne* la *jamais* revoir" aussi (je crois?)

Comment: @LPH - je me demande s'il ne faut pas ajouter un "ne" pour compléter la forme négative "ne ... jamais". "Enfin, elle reçut une lettre de cette écriture qu'elle n'avait presque plus l'espoir de jamais revoir" me semble tout à fait acceptable, avec le même sens.

Comment: @Frank Je crois qu'il ne faut pas du tout la particule ; voici ce qu'on trouve au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jamais) dans la section « sans particule » : « − [Avec une idée de renoncement] − Oui! murmurait Pencroff. C'était un homme celui-là, et un vrai! − C'était... dit Harbert. Est-ce que tu désespères de le revoir jamais? (Verne, Île myst.,1874, p. 36).Mais faut-il donc renoncer à voir jamais la médecine scientifique fondée sur la physiologie (...)? (Cl. Bernard, Princ. méd. exp.,1878, p. 298). ».

Comment: @Frank À propos de ce [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52768/analyse-grammaticale-dune-phrase-dans-via-mala-de-john-knittel/52770?noredirect=1#comment110461_52770) : les impressions sont une chose, à ne pas négliger, mais finalement, en particulier dans ce domaine de la grammaire on ne peut se fier qu'à un raisonnement, dans le cas présent, à un raisonnement qui montre qu'il n'existe pas de mots grammaticaux redondants, de relations impropres, etc.

Comment: @LPH J'offre seulement mon expérience vécue. La langue évolue en permanence, et la grammaire n'est pas forcèment suivie en pratique.